# error message from installing Python package "pattern" in AWS SageMaker

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install `pattern` Python package in AWS SageMaker notebook instance, but got the error as following:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ju5nnjq1/mysqlclient_3c5ff462d7f94f949b3e3912b9f6bb16/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ju5nnjq1/mysqlclient_3c5ff462d7f94f949b3e3912b9f6bb16/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ju5nnjq1/mysqlclient_3c5ff462d7f94f949b3e3912b9f6bb16/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

When I am using my local machine (macOS), I solved the issue by typing the following command.

```
brew install mysql
```

How can I do the same thing in AWS SagaMaker notebook instance terminal? Thank you.

Comment: I installed `mysql`  by `brew install mysql` and it works. Thank you.